# install bootstrap to grails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grails

I'm new to grails, I can't find a good tutorial to install bootstrap in grails 3+ (3.1.5), and I can't get what the plugin "twitter bootstrap plugin" is exactly for, isn't it enough to replace layouts/main.gsp with a bootstrap template? is It recommanded to use bootstrap with grails or there is a better alternative? Thank you
**EDIT :**
The correct answer is the one given by Jeff Scott Brown in comment
*"If you are using Grails 3, Bootstrap is installed in a newly created app by default. You don't have to install it."*

Comment: If you are using Grails 3, Bootstrap is installed in a newly created app by default.  You don't have to install it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**BASICS** 
Boostrap can be added to you project just by adding the files (one css and one javascript) to your html pages. As you will need to include those files in all the pages, I suggest putting the files in the layout files. 
**BOOTSTRAP** 
You are using bootstrap by giving specific class names to your `div`s. Bootstrap just adds their specific css to make it neat and responsive. You can read more about it all [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). 
**INCLUDING** 
To add those files, you need to add this to your html layout or just one page:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can also download the files and prevent from losing the functionality offline. Then download it from [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

**EXTRA INFO** 
In case you are not familiar with grails layouts, you can check them out in [this link](http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-layout-templates/) 
It's very simple actually. You just define all the `head` stuff in there.

Comment: Thank you, can I make the layout "dynamic" for example add condiitons to show/hide "links" in function of the user privileges ?

Comment: Are you using spring security?

Comment: No, i'm new to grails I don't know what "spring security" used for

Comment: If you are using users and authorization, spring security is the way to go. DEFINATELY check it out. And to check the user role in gsp page, you can write With spring sec. you can use it like this - `<sec:access expression="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">`

Answer (score 1):

You can install Bootstrap of normal way, ie, adding manually the bootstrap files in your project, in your web-app directory. Then, you only have to add it to layouts or pages (.gsp).

Also, you can add it manually in assets directory. With this way, you only type once time in your layout the load with: **g:asset**.

Or if you prefer to use the plugin, here a spanish tutorial: http://abel-olguin.com/anadir-twitter-bootstrap-a-grails-3/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't talk spanish :/ what's the utility of the plugin please? what makes it better then doing it manually?

Comment: This plugin simplifies how to add Bootstrap in all pages because it is located in assets. There is no difference in functionality between the two ways.